# AssertionError instead of failure

Tags: ant, junit, junit4, swtbot

i have developed a test package using SWTbot and ant to build it , when i run it, it finds  that there is a failure however in the test report it shows as an error instead of failure:
my code is :

```
    public static void Check_TargetPack(final SWTWorkbenchBot bot,String configuration,
        String targetpack) {
    boolean exist=false;
            String[] h=bot.comboBoxWithLabel("TargetPack").items();
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<h.length;i++){
        if (h[i]==targetpack)exist=true;
        assertTrue("target pack"+targetpack+" doesn't exist in targetpack list",exist);
    };

    bot.sleep(2000);
    bot.button("Close").click();

}
```

and the result is [image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem in your code.
You are matching Strings with "==" operator.
You should use following instead

```
h[i].equals(targetpack)
```